# Rejecting request with specific key value pair in the request body in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to return a bad request response with error message

`{"error":"Cannot assign commentId from client"}` is the request body in the `POST` request has a `commentId` field with a non-null/empty/blank value.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class CommentsRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> commentsRoute(CommentsHandler commentsHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(GET("/v1/comments/{parentId}"), commentsHandler::getComments)
                .andRoute(GET("/v1/comments/{commentId}"), commentsHandler::getComment)
                .andRoute(POST("/v1/comments").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), commentsHandler::addComment)
                .filter(((request, next) -> {
                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>() {{
                        put("error", "Pre-assigned commentId is not allowed");
                    }};
                    Map<String, String> emptyBody = new HashMap<>() {{
                        put("error", "No content found while creating comment");
                    }};
                    if (request.path().equalsIgnoreCase("/v1/comments") && request.methodName().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
                        try {
                            request.bodyToMono(Comment.class)
                                    .single()
                                    .filter(comment -> Objects.nonNull(comment.getCommentId()))
                                    .flatMap(comment -> {
                                        log.error("Pre-Assigned commentId found in payload {} for {} request {}", comment, request.methodName(), request.path());
                                        return ServerResponse.badRequest().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(BodyInserters.fromValue(error));
                                    });
                        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                            log.error("Empty body found for request {}", request.path());
                            return ServerResponse.badRequest().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(BodyInserters.fromValue(emptyBody));
                        }
                    }
                    return next.handle(request);
                }));
    }
}
```

When I run a test I notice that the none of the code in the `try` block runs even when the `if` holds true; how do I evaluate a condition based on the contents of RequestBody and return a 400 Response?

On a (related) design question, should I move this logic of throwing error if commentId exists to the service that the handler associated with this router would call?

Comment: You are not subscribing to `request.bodyToMono...` , hence nothing runs

Comment: I have no clue what means! :-) please translate to Reactor Noob'lish